How to deploy a MinkowskiEngine-based neural network for use in a C# application?
I am attempting to deploy a neural network that I have developed using the MinkowskiEngine framework. I have successfully developed and tested this network on my local machine, and now I wish to deploy it to a server. Can anyone provide guidance or recommend some resources for this process?
Here are my current environment specifications:

Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04
Python Version: 3.11
MinkowskiEngine Version: 0.5
Server Type: My personal computer with Windows 11 Subsystem for Linux (WSL)

My specific challenge is:

I am unsure how to proceed with the deployment, and it seems that MinkowskiEngine does not support exporting to ONNX.

Any advice on deployment strategies, or related experiences would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
How to deploy a MinkowskiEngine-based neural network for use in a C# application?
